# If $p$ divides $a$ but not $b$ does $p$ divide $a^2+b^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$p$ is a prime number and $a$, $b$ are integers. If $p$ divides $a$ but not $b$, does $p$ divide $a^2+b^2$?

Comment: Until you specify what $p,a,b$ are exactly, no "proof" can be made, strictly speaking. Usually $p$ denotes a prime number, but $p$ is not reserved for prime numbers like $\mathbb{R}$ for the real field.

Comment: Sorry, corrected

Comment: Say not that. I am trying to say that it is an accountability for every math writer to be of clarity. And specifying symbols' types are of the minimum requirement, let alone the quantifier issue...

Comment: $$ p\mid a \implies p\mid a^2$$ $$p\mid a^2 \land p\mid(a^2+b^2)\implies p\mid b^2$$ $$p\mid b^2\implies p\mid b.$$

Comment: I don't know that p divides a^2+b^2. I know that p divides a and p does not divide b. Can p then divide a^2+b^2?

Comment: I know that $p\mid(a^2+b^2)$ is not one of the hypotheses. But can't you see that it means $p\mid a$ and $p\mid (a^2+b^2)$ is not consistent with $p\nmid b$?

Comment: I can see it intuitively but why? How can I prove that?

Comment: Easy counter-example: Let $p = a$ be any prime, $b = 1$. Then $p \nmid a^2+b^2 = p^2+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that we're dealing with integers and that $p$ is a prime.

If $p$ divides $a$ and $p$ divides $a^2+b^2$, then $p$ divides $b^2$ and so divides $b$.

Comment: I don't know that p divides a^2+b^2. I know that p divides a and p does not divide b. Can p then divide a^2+b^2?

Comment: @user271836, the argument above says: *If* $p$ divided $a^2+b^2$ then $p$ would divide $b$, also known as the contrapositive.

Comment: @user271836: The answer proves that $p$ does not divide $a^2+b^2$. For if it did then $p$ would divide $b$ contrary to hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Since $p|a^2$, you only need to care about whether $p|b^2$. I think you can use some counter-example to show that it does not always true. like $a=2,b=3,p=2$

Comment: I don't want to show that it's not always true, I want to show that it's always false

Answer (score 0):

We have $p|a\implies \exists m \in Z, a=mp$.

$p|a^2+b^2\implies kp=a^2+b^2=m^2p^2+b^2$

$\implies b^2=kp-m^2p^2=p(k-m^2)\implies p|b^2\implies p|b$

So $(p|a) \land p|(a^2+b^2) \implies p|b$

So by modus tollens and DeMorgan's laws,

$\lnot(p|b) \implies \lnot(p|a) \lor \lnot(p|a^2+b^2)$

But we are given $p|a$ so we must have $\lnot (p|a^2+b^2)$

Uses a logic rule:

$(A \lor B) \land  \lnot A\implies  B$